# JFrame pierde conexion a base de datos

Tags: java-swing, derby

Estoy trabajando con JFrames(login, mainMenu, Administracion, Ventas) en una aplicacion similar a un inventario y ventas de supermercado, como almacenamiento en ejecucion estoy trabajando con un arbol binario de busqueda para representar como nodos cada articulo del inventario(se que no es ideal) y uso una base de datos(Derby Embedded) para almacenar la informacion a largo plazo.
El problema es que cuando le envio el dato de la coneccion a la DB a "Administracion" para que se encargue de agregar articulos al inventario, este JFrame no parece recibir los datos de conexion y me retorna este log de errores:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Sin conexión actual.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.noCurrentConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.checkIfClosed(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.setupContextStack(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at BackEnd.BaseDeDatos.insertarEnBase(BaseDeDatos.java:76)
at BackEnd.ArbolDeBusquedaBinaria.insertar(ArbolDeBusquedaBinaria.java:123)
at FrontEnd.Administracion.agregarArtActionPerformed(Administracion.java:272)
at FrontEnd.Administracion.access$300(Administracion.java:25)
at FrontEnd.Administracion$4.actionPerformed(Administracion.java:126)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper$5.dispatchEvent(AtkWrapper.java:700)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Sin conexión actual.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 50 more

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 4 seconds)
```

¿Cual podria ser la razon de este error?
La verdad no estoy seguro si lo que estoy tratando de hacer es una mala practica o si es totalmente imposible de hacer.
Dejo aqui el [enlace al proyecto de Netbeans en GitHub](https://github.com/xinoxkai/SistemaIntegradoDeSupermercado) para que tengan una mejor idea de como he hecho la aplicacion. Gracias.

Comment: Si compartes el código nos ayudarías a ayudarte.

Comment: Si, en el enlace a GitHub es donde esta el código fuente.